# Proof horizontal translation rule of a function $f(x+c)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Is it possible to demonstrate that $f(x+c)$ with $c>0$ is the left horizontal translation of the function $f(x)$? I would like to demonstrate it formally, without any examples.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't that the left translation?

Comment: What is your definition of a translation?

Comment: Hi @Nameless, sorry for my  mistake.

Comment: Hi @Marc, now I'm adding some informations (orizontal traslation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be some point on the graph of $y=f(x)$. After applying a left translation by $c$ units, we obtain the point $(x_0-c,y_0)$. Since $f((x_0-c)+c)=f(x_0)=y_0$, we see that $(x_0-c,y_0)$ lies on the graph of $y=f(x+c)$.

Therefore, the graph of $y=f(x)$ followed by the translation, is a subset of the graph of $y=f(x+c)$. Similarly, you can show that the latter is a subset of the former. So the two graphs are just identical.